# Como eliminar objeto de Array Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Tengo esta variable

> var almacen = [];

a la cual luego le hago un .push con los datos similar a esto

> almacen.push([id,extension,descripcion]);

Y a lo largo del modulo voy haciendo varios .push dentro de ese array.

mostrandome como resultado en un alart algo como esto ( en caso de tener 3 .push ya hechos)

> [[0,"docx","Comentario 1"],[1,"docx","Comentario 2"],[2,"docx","Comentario 3"]]

Por lo que la pregunta concreta seria como eliminar uno de esos elementos completamente, para que quede algo como esto por ejemplo:

> [[0,"docx","Comentario 1"],[2,"docx","Comentario 3"]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas:

Por ejemplo con el método *delete* puedes borrar el contenido, pero en el caso de un array el valor del índice se destruye aunque no el índice. Como verás en este ejemplo, el primer índice del array pasa a ser undefined pero la longitud del array en ambos casos es 3.

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
console.log(a);
delete(a[0]);
console.log(a);
```

Este método no es el mejor para eliminar índices de arrays. Quizás sea más apropiado para eliminar propiedades de objetos.

Podemos utilizar sin embargo el método splice para eliminar completamente el índice, como puedes ver en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
console.log(a);
a.splice(0,1);
console.log(a);
```

La función *splice* acepta dos argumentos (acepta más pero en nuestro ejemplo es suficiente con conocer solo los dos primeros). El primero es el índice a partir del cual quieres hacer el borrado. El segundo es el número de elementos que vas a borrar (a partir de ese índice). En nuestro caso, al poner *splice(0,1)* estamos diciendo que borre el primer índice y sólo ese.

```js
var a = [[0,"docx","Comentario 1"],[1,"docx","Comentario 2"],[2,"docx","Comentario 3"]];

console.log(a);

a.splice(1,1);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu acotacion, el problema es que no quiere solo eliminar un indice de un array, yo quiero eliminar el objeto completo, Ve el ejemplo que coloque de lo que quiero y de daras cuenta que hay doble [ [Objeto1],[Objeto 2] ], claro dentro de cada objeto estan los indices pero quiero eliminar el objeto completo.

Comment: @MaikerLeon, he replicado tu ejemplo en el último código. No es eso lo que quieres? Ten en cuenta que al eliminar el indice, eliminas todo lo que haya asociado a ese índice, y si tienes un objeto asociado como es tu caso, lo eliminará por completo.

Comment: Perfecto, pense que todo era como el primer ejemplo disculpa Cooper muchas gracias :D